# Evolution keeps asking me for password authentication (gnome shell)

Tags: password, evolution, gnome-shell-extension

Every time I open my dash, I see the dash display as normal. But once I type into the dash search bar, I receive a request for password authentication for evolution. This is incredibly frustrating! Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known Bug, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1299604)

I looked through some of the comments and there are a few proposed workarounds.

- **Remove the account**:
  Not really a solution. Nevertheless: Go to Settings, Accounts, select the perpetrator and click on remove. A notable alternative E-Mail client is Thunderbird.
- **Set the period for checking for new mail**:
  Go to Settings, Accounts, select the culprit, click edit and set the "Check new email every ... minutes" setting to some random time other than "Default", after this you will reportedly be asked for the password only once, right after login.
- **Reset your keyrings, reinstall Seahorse**:
  Remove everything in `~/.gnome2/keyrings/`, uninstall Seahorse, reboot, enter the password when Evolution asks for it, close Evolution, reinstall Seahorse, open Evolution again, enter the password again, this time Evolutions should remember it. Detailed instructions [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1299604/comments/11). Be careful though, resetting your keyring might not be something you want to do.
- **Install patches**:
  [This one](https://git.gnome.org/browse/evolution-data-server/commit/?h=evolution-data-server-3-12&id=c9f9cdebfc) and [this one](https://git.gnome.org/browse/evolution-data-server/commit/?h=evolution-data-server-3-12&id=fedfc8f). I haven't tested them though and the comment is from 2014, and I encountered this bug in 2016 (on Ubuntu 14.04, admittedly), so they might be already incorporated in the official releases and might not actually solve the issue.
- **Read the comments on the bugtracker**:
  There are more suggestions for solutions and workarounds in the page linked above, If you're not happy with the points listed here, you might find one that works for you there.